# Differential Equations Variations of Parameters and Constant Term

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometric-integrals

I have a general question about constant terms and trigonometric integrals. The question revolves about why pulling out this $\frac12$ term is important. This is the differential equation I was given\begin{equation} y''+y=\sin(x) \end{equation} From that I get the auxiliary equation which is the following: \begin{equation} m^2+1=0 \end{equation} From there I get these two known solutions to the homogeneous portion of the equation: \begin{equation}y_h= c_1\cos(x)+c_2\sin(x)\end{equation} From here I calculate the Wronskian of the known homogeneous solutions: \begin{equation}W=\begin{vmatrix} \cos(x) & \sin(x) \\ -\sin(x) & \cos(x) \end{vmatrix} \end{equation}From there I get the determinant which turns out to be 1, since it is a Pythagorean Identity. From here since I know its a two by two matrix for  the numerators of the u's, I am still going to set up the Wronksians for the problem. \begin{equation} u'_1=\frac{\begin{vmatrix} 0 & \sin(x) \\ \sin(x) & \cos(x)\end{vmatrix}}{1}=-\sin^2(x)\end{equation}Then integrating $u'_1(x)$. \begin{equation}u=-\int \frac12-\frac{\cos(2x)}{2}dx=\frac{\sin(2x)}{4}-\frac x2  \end{equation}
The first particular turns out to be $y_1u_1$, which is $\frac{\cos(x)\sin(2x)}{4}-\frac{x\cos(x)}{2}$ Now comes $u'_2(x)$, which one gets from the Wronskians. \begin{equation}u'_2(x)= \frac{\begin{vmatrix} \cos(x) & 0 \\ -\sin(x) & \sin(x) \end{vmatrix}}1 \end{equation} Then I get for $u_2$: \begin{equation} u_2=\int u'_2 dx = \int \sin(x)\cos(x) dx\end{equation} Using U-Substitution I get the following: $\frac{\sin^2(x)}{2}$
When I compose together the particular I get the following:
$$y_p=\frac{\cos(x)\sin(2x)}{4}-\frac{x\cos(x)}{2}+\frac{\sin^3(x)}2$$
But Symbolab gives me $\frac{-x\cos(x)}{2}$ Is my answer wrong....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well

$$\frac{1}{2}\sin^3(x) + \frac{1}{4}\cos(x)\sin(2x) = \frac{1}{2}\sin(x)$$

And this part can be absorbed into your general solution. Leaving you with just $\frac{-x\cos(x)}{2}$ in your particular solution.

Comment: Smart didn't think about it that way.

Comment: I was confused because I was graphing the particular and saw it was off by a little bit so I thought I missed a term but the absorbed into the general solution makes total sense.

Comment: Thanks +1 even posted my answer .

Answer (score 1):

To add more detail to Dayton's answer this can be done a number of ways, and one of those ways being the following: \begin{equation}\frac{1}{2}\sin(x)(\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2})+ \frac{\cos(x)\sin(2x)}{4}\end{equation} This then simplifies to the following: \begin{equation}\frac{\sin(x)}{4}-\frac{\sin(x)\cos(2x)}{4}+\frac{\cos(x)\sin(2x)}{4}=\frac{\sin(x)}4+\frac{\sin(x)}4 \end{equation}
Which is pretty neat I realized that you have this:
\begin{equation}y=c_1\cos(x)+(c_2+\frac 12)\sin(x)-\frac{x\cos(x)}2 \end{equation}
Due to the self absorbing c it becomes the following: \begin{equation}y=c_1\cos(x)+c_2\sin(x)-\frac{x\cos(x)}{2} \end{equation}

Comment: This is good details, I just used Wolfram https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%5E3%28x%29%2F2+%2B+cos%28x%29sin%282x%29%2F4 . Sometimes the particular solutions can have scalar multiples of the the general solution. In this case it is because the forcing term is also a solution to the homogeneous part.

Comment: @Dayton Dude I hate that makes me think I am wrong so I am guess now adding everything to homogenous its for my DE intro class.